# maven build including extra jars in manifest file

Tags: java, maven, manifest, netbeans-8

I'm using Maven to build jars for my application. When I create jar using maven build on Netbeans it creates the jar as expected and it adds all the jars in manifest file those are present in my POM file but along with those jars it also adds some extra jars to POM file as well that are I think related to dependencies I have used in POM (Not sure if this is the case). when these extra jars including my manifest file these are creating problem for me and when I remove these extra jars from the manifest file my jars work fine.

The other solution for this issue is that I add these extra jars to the server, which I don't want to do.

Here is plugin part of my POM file that is populating details in manifest.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.contingent.wug.SitePerformanceAnalysis</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm sure im missing any property that will help me to avoid adding these extra jars but not sure what is that. Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

Here is the only dependency of my POM file. 
[image]

but when I see the dependencies folder of my project here is the list of dependencies I can see where I'm only expecting one dependency.

[image]

its OK if I am having these number of jars to project but I don't want to add all of them to manifest file.

Comment: Maybe you should just identify those problematic transitive dependencies and explicitly exclude them...?

Comment: yes, im doing the same right now, but it is a hectic activity to refine all the jars.

Comment: I meant exclude them from the pom file, not from manifest files... http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: Let me update question ... im only adding sqlserver jar but i can see 10s of other jars in my project and those are adding to manifest ...

Comment: Try to remove this line: <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>

Comment: When I check the dependency tree under that mssql driver, I see many transitive dependencies. You'll have to find the one breaking your runtime and exclude it. There's no other way. Removing all dependencies may simply cause your driver to stop working.